# Is there a way to create Polylines in the Google Earth API using the Google Maps v3 DirectionsService?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth

I'm not sure this is the right group. If not, please let me know.

My dilemma:

I need to add `Polylines` to Google Earth from the results I get back from the Google Maps v3 `DirectionsService`. There seems to be nothing on the web to that extent. It has to be possible, because Roman does this in his driving simulator: http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/drive-simulator/index.html

Unfortunately, he is using Google Maps v2 there and I can't seem to figure out how to transfer this code into Google Maps v3.

Comment: You can answer your own question! I suggest transferring your solution to an answer (which you can also accept, but maybe not immediately).

Comment: There is a 2 day waiting period to answer your own question, but yes, please follow the advice and answer your own question after the waiting period has expired.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, here is how I managed to solve it:

```
function DrawLinesOnEarth() {
    var sLat;
    var sLon;
    //var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    //var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var request = {
        origin: '40.306134,-74.05018',
        destination: '40.313223,-74.043496',
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            var steps = result.routes[0].legs[0].steps;

            //Step through array of step legs and create polylines one by one
            var lineStringPlacemark = IMC_ge.createPlacemark('');
            var lineString = IMC_ge.createLineString('');
            lineStringPlacemark.setGeometry(lineString);
            // Add LineString points
            for (var x in steps) {
                for (var y in steps[x].path) {
                    sLat = steps[x].path[y].Na;
                    sLon = steps[x].path[y].Oa;
                    lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(sLat, sLon, 0);
                }
            }
            // Add the feature to Earth
            IMC_ge.getFeatures().appendChild(lineStringPlacemark);

        }
    });
}
```